# MS SQL Server - Export Results To File without "NULL"

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssms

I am using SQL Server Management Studio to export the results of my query to text. I would like to export the results without the character NULL being printed between delimiters.

For example, instead of:

```
,NULL,
```

I would like to export:

```
,,
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just simply use

```
ISNULL(someColumn, '')
```

in our query. This will replace all `NULL` values with an empty string

Comment: Is there an easier way, such as some kind of setting that I can turn nulls off?

Comment: @user1518630: no there is not

Comment: Note that this will only work for character fields. If you use this on a date or numeric field, those rows with a NULL value won't show up in the results, and SQL Server won't complain about the data type mismatch.

Comment: I take SMS's standard query which lists all the fields in a column and use Shift+ALT to add ISNULL to all fields at once. I can also take all the field names and add them as an "AS" with Shift+Alt.

Comment: Years later... I'm still searching for a solution... and yet I'm still being directed to the same answer... ugh.  Now to go into myquery and wrap every field with an IsNull()... yikes - If I could use Oracle's SQL Developer to access SQL Server...

Comment: One of my favorite all time tricks is to let SQL write my SQL. I'm adding another response @CodeNovice

Comment: Still coming back to this answer.  Still no easy way to remove the never asked for text of "NULL". We get it... it's null now stop putting it in my data please.

Comment: Bummer... same answer two years later.  STILL LOOKING FOR a normal solution.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you export the data. If you use the Import and Export Wizard, the NULL strings do not show up in the result file (tested with SQL Server Management Studio 2014).

Select Tasks -> Export Data... In the dialog where you choose the destination, select "Flat File Destination". You can then write a custom query to select the data.

Comment: How will this work for outputting the results of a query (as per the original question) rather than a table?

Comment: @kh42874 The process I described should work for outputting the results of a query. This is what I meant by "a custom query". More specifically, in the wizard step "Specify Table Copy or Query" you can select the option "Write a query to specify the data to transfer" and then write your query there.

Answer (score 0):

I love letting SQL write my SQL. This expands on the answer from @marc_s, addresses the datatype issue brought up by @HardCode, and makes it easy like @hamel requested.

Automatic code generation is a great labor-saving approach for tasks like this, and the INFORMATION_SCHEMA makes it possible in SQL.

```
-- Sample data.
drop table if exists #null_demo;
create table #null_demo (
    int_col int,
    numeric_col numeric(10, 2),
    varchar_col varchar(50),
    date_col date,
    datetime_col datetime2
    );
insert into #null_demo values (1, 2.0, 'string', getdate(), getdate())
insert into #null_demo values (null, 2.0, 'string', getdate(), getdate())
insert into #null_demo values (1,null, 'string', getdate(), getdate())
insert into #null_demo values (1, 2.0, null, getdate(), getdate())
insert into #null_demo values (1, 2.0, 'string', null, getdate())
insert into #null_demo values (1, 2.0, 'string', getdate(), null)

-- Ordinary select returns NULL
select  *
from    #null_demo

-- Observe INFORMATION_SCHEMA
select  *
from    TEMPDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where   TABLE_NAME like '#null_demo%'

-- Let SQL write your SQL.
select  COLUMN_NAME+' = isnull(cast('+COLUMN_NAME+' as varchar), ''''),'
from    TEMPDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where   TABLE_NAME like '#null_demo%'
```

Copy the results into a query and delete the final trailing comma.

```
select  int_col = isnull(cast(int_col as varchar), ''),
        numeric_col = isnull(cast(numeric_col as varchar), ''),
        varchar_col = isnull(cast(varchar_col as varchar), ''),
        date_col = isnull(cast(date_col as varchar), ''),
        datetime_col = isnull(cast(datetime_col as varchar), '')
from    #null_demo
```

When I set the text output format to comma delimited and include the column headers (see Query->Query Options->Text), and return the results as text, I get this back.

```
int_col,numeric_col,varchar_col,date_col,datetime_col
1,2.00,string,2021-08-19,2021-08-19 14:44:00.5466667
,2.00,string,2021-08-19,2021-08-19 14:44:00.5466667
1,,string,2021-08-19,2021-08-19 14:44:00.5466667
1,2.00,,2021-08-19,2021-08-19 14:44:00.5466667
1,2.00,string,,2021-08-19 14:44:00.5466667
1,2.00,string,2021-08-19,
```

I can send that to a file, too.

Comment: Very good, but a very complicated solution to a problem that shouldn't exist in the first place!