# Compress the pivot table result to one row in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to have a single line result in SQL pivot table like below

```
+------------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| Request_id | IT Review | SO Review | Approved |
+------------+-----------+-----------+----------+
|    11111   |    09-19  |   09-20   |   09-21  |
+------------+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

However, I can't get rid of the null value in the columns:

```
+------------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| Request_id | IT Review | SO Review | Approved |
+------------+-----------+-----------+----------+
|   11111    |   09-19   |    NULL   |   NULL   |
|   11111    |    NULL   |   09-20   |   NULL   |
|   11111    |    NULL   |    NULL   |  09-21   |
+------------+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

Below is my query, could anyone please shed some lights on how to revise my query? Thanks!

```
   SELECT [Request_ID] [Request ID]
        ,[IT Review]
        ,[SO Review]
        ,[Approved]
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM [RptChange].[dbo].[tRequestsAudit] a
        JOIN (
            SELECT [reqID] [Request_ID]
                ,MIN([reqUpdateDt]) [UpdateDT]
                ,MIN([AuditID]) AS EarliestAuditID
                ,[reqStatus] SubStatus
            FROM [RptChange].[dbo].[tRequestsAudit]
            WHERE [reqID] = 102943
            GROUP BY [reqStatus]
                ,[reqID]
            ) sub ON sub.[EarliestAuditID] = a.AuditID
        ) sub2
    PIVOT(MIN([UpdateDT]) FOR sub2.reqStatus IN (
                [IT Review]
                ,[SO Review]
                ,[Approved]
                )) AS P
```

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17323446/ms-sql-server-export-results-to-file-without-null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replace

```
SELECT *
```

with

```
SELECT DISTINCT sub.Request_ID, sub.UpdateDT,a.reqStatus
```

Something like that:

```
   SELECT [Request_ID] [Request ID]
        ,[IT Review]
        ,[SO Review]
        ,[Approved]
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT sub.Request_ID, sub.UpdateDT,a.reqStatus
        FROM [RptChange].[dbo].[tRequestsAudit] a
        JOIN (
            SELECT [reqID] [Request_ID]
                ,MIN([reqUpdateDt]) [UpdateDT]
                ,MIN([AuditID]) AS EarliestAuditID
                ,[reqStatus] SubStatus
            FROM [RptChange].[dbo].[tRequestsAudit]
            WHERE [reqID] = 102943
            GROUP BY [reqStatus]
                ,[reqID]
            ) sub ON sub.[EarliestAuditID] = a.AuditID
        ) sub2
    PIVOT(MIN([UpdateDT]) FOR sub2.reqStatus IN (
                [IT Review]
                ,[SO Review]
                ,[Approved]
                )) AS P
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [Request_ID] [Request ID]
        ,[IT Review]
        ,[SO Review]
        ,[Approved]
    FROM (
        SELECT sub.[Request_ID], sub.SubStatus, sub.UpdateDT
        FROM [dbo].[tRequestsAudit] a
        JOIN (
            SELECT [reqID] [Request_ID]
                ,MIN([reqUpdateDt]) [UpdateDT]
                ,MIN([AuditID]) AS EarliestAuditID
                ,[reqStatus] SubStatus
            FROM [dbo].[tRequestsAudit]
            WHERE [reqID] = 1
            GROUP BY [reqStatus]
                ,[reqID]
            ) sub ON sub.[EarliestAuditID] = a.AuditID
        ) sub2
    PIVOT(MIN([UpdateDT]) FOR sub2.SubStatus IN (
                [IT Review]
                ,[SO Review]
                ,[Approved]
                )) AS P
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not trying to change the time format but I want to compress the pivot table result to one line.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a convoluted method, but a pivot result can be compressed using dynamic SQL.
The demo data I set up (#data) represents the output of a pivot query where the values end up staggered as described in the question.

The logic here is that an inner query linking a table to itself  (correlated subquery) where the top 1 value of an ordered results set is taken will bring all the results relating to that ID onto one row. Dynamic SQL enables you to generate the query without having to hard code this across many rows and columns.

This solution is written and tested in Transact SQL for MS SQL Server.

```
-- create temp table to store demo data
CREATE TABLE #data (Request_id int, 
                [IT Review] nvarchar(5),
                [SO Review] nvarchar(5),
                [Approved] nvarchar(5)
                )

-- add data to demo table
INSERT INTO #data
    VALUES (11111, '09-19', NULL, NULL),
        (11111, NULL, '09-20', NULL),
        (11111, NULL, NULL, '09-21')

-- view demo data
SELECT * FROM #data

-- view the column name data that will be used to generate the query
SELECT  name, column_id --INTO #table
FROM tempdb.sys.columns 
    WHERE object_id =
        object_id('tempdb..#data')
        ORDER BY column_id

-- declare variables to store the query in
DECLARE @inner_query AS VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @outer_query AS VARCHAR(MAX)

-- generate the inner query, the part to take the only non null value (top 1) based on 
-- schema tables in the tempdb and relates this to the outer query via table alias t1. 
-- ensure to exclude the id column as this is only for the outer query
SET @inner_query = STUFF((SELECT '(SELECT TOP 1 ' + QUOTENAME(name) 
                                + ' FROM #data WHERE [Request_id] = t1.[Request_id] 
                                AND '
                                + QUOTENAME(name) 
                                + ' IS NOT NULL ) AS '
                                + QUOTENAME(name) + ','
                    FROM tempdb.sys.columns 
                    WHERE object_id = object_id('tempdb..#data')
                        AND name != 'Request_id'
                    GROUP BY name, column_id
                    ORDER BY column_id
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                ,1,1,'')

-- view inner query
SELECT @inner_query

-- clean inner query to add required bracket at start and remove the comma at the end
SET @inner_query = '(' + (SELECT SUBSTRING(@inner_query, 1, LEN(@inner_query)-1))

-- view cleaned inner query
SELECT @inner_query

-- set the outer query, to which the inner query matches (using WHERE id=id)
SET @outer_query = 'SELECT [Request_id], ' + @inner_query 
            + 'FROM #data t1 
            GROUP BY t1.[Request_id] ORDER BY t1.[Request_id]'

-- view final query
SELECT @outer_query

-- execute the query
EXECUTE(@outer_query)

DROP TABLE #data
```